# How can I get my MacBook to use my second hard drive for storing photos?

Tags: macos, photos.app, storage

My disk is getting full, probably because I have so many pictures. How can I remove images and how can I specify the location where the images are stored from iOS devices such as iPhone and iPad? I use iPhone in OS X.

I have two harddrives in my MacBook, and I want to use the empty hard drive, but I don't know how I can instruct OS X to use it more. My main harddrive is running out of storage all the time.